# Error during download: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Tags: python, gdown

I am unable to download audio files from my google drive.

```py
import gdown

drive_link = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1X13DtRGrF2gFVYL_2bVZ9OtiuSQGnl'
file_id = drive_link.split('=')[1]  
output_path = f"/Users/Udita/Desktop/AudioFiles/downloaded_file.ext"

try:
    gdown.download(drive_link, output_path, fuzzy=True)
    print("File downloaded successfully with fuzzy option.")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during download: {e}")
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the programming language you are using (it looks like Python, but lacks the proper indention) and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: The [drive] tag is for physical disk drives; not for Google drive.

Comment: You should also include the full error.

Answer (score 7):

For those that need a quick and naive solution:

Don't know which package is being updated recently under gdown dependencies but installing a lower version of it solves it

```
pip install gdown==v4.6.0
```

ref https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/issues/291#issuecomment-1887060708

Comment: That didn't work for me. However, downgrading to 4.6.0 did work.

Comment: Yes, 4.6.0 works for me, but not 4.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting to replace in download.py file this:

```
m = re.search(r"filename\*=UTF-8''(.*)", content_disposition)
```

with this:

```
m = re.search('filename="(.*)"', content_disposition)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade version to 4.6.3 ([issue 292](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/issues/292))

Or you can update download.py like @user23232049 mentionned upper

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue. Try:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(drive_link, filename=output_path)
```

instead. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the resolution of [issue 809](https://github.com/mlcommons/GaNDLF/pull/809), I resolved the issue with

```
pip install 'gdown>=5.1.0'
```